# What is the best strategy to extract information from a GNU Savannah issue?

Tags: python, issue-tracking

Given a URL like http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?23435, what's the best way to extract information like:

1: project title: Gnash - The GNU Flash player

2: issue title: Flash content rendered above menus in Firefox

Answer (score 1):

You can use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import re

response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?23435')
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

p_title = soup.select('.toptitle')[0].text
# 'Gnash - The GNU Flash player - Bugs: bug #23435, Flash content rendered above menus...'
p_title = p_title.split(' - Bugs:')[0]

i_title = soup.select('.priore')[0].text
# 'bug #23435: Flash content rendered above menus in Firefox'
i_title = re.findall('bug #[0-9]*: (.+)', i_title)[0]

print(p_title)
# 'Gnash - The GNU Flash player'
print(i_title)
# 'Flash content rendered above menus in Firefox'
```

(Python 3)

Comment: Thanks. I would prefer to use a XML or JSON API if available. But I might have to do as you suggest.